# CMV goto widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I have a problem with [Goto](https://github.com/BrianBunker/cmv-widgets/tree/master//Goto) widget, it doesn't display anything, the error displayed is that proj4.js is not found, I copy and paste the folder Goto in my project and it keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: I have not used the "Goto" widget, but my "Projection" widget has similar functionality: https://github.com/tr3vorm/cmv-projections-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a path to proj4 in your dojo config. Otherwise, dojo will not be able to find proj4 library and will throw the error you are experiencing.

If you are using the latest version of cmv, you will have a file, `config/app`. If you're not using the latest version of cmv, your dojo config will be located in the `index.html` file.

In the dojo config, look for the `packages` section. Add the proj4 package using the following code:

```
packages: [{
    name: 'proj4js',
    location: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.3'
},
//......other packages
]
```

This should make the error go away.